# Creating a function on matlab that adds numbers to the end of words

Tags: matlab

[Said question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAixI.png)

Dear Guys,

I have only just started using matlab and as such am not too sure how to answer this question for my problem set.

Would anyone be able to help me out with this?

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Because it's your lucky day, I'll post an answer which solves it in a non-obvious way, but from which you can learn the most.

Or, you know, get a good grade but fail the course.

Next time, please do an attempt yourself *first*; SO is not a coding service.

```
function string = uniqueword(string)

    persistent calls
    if isempty(calls)
        calls = 0; end

    maxcalls = 5;

    assert(ischar(string),...
           [mfilename ':invalid_argument'],...
           '%s takes a single string argument.',...
           mfilename);

    assert(calls <= maxcalls,...
           [mfilename ':maxcalls_exceeded'],...
           '%d words have already been created.',...
           maxcalls);

    calls  = calls + 1;
    string = [string calls+48];

end
```

Comment: down-voted mine too, so I just deleted it. Guess helping people gets a down-vote. Counter productive but whatever... :(